# IE 10 Browser Ajax Call Issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax, internet-explorer

I have one Api to get html content,something like this

"http://localhost/somefolder/coneten#/home"

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/somefolder/coneten#/home",
    dataType:"json",
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log();
    },
    success:function(json) {
             console.log();
    }
});
```

When i run my application in IE 10 browser i am getting 404 error because of IE converting my api into

"http://localhost/somefolder/coneten%23/home"(# into %23)

So it is not hitting server.
but in all the other browsers it is working and url is not converting.
Please anybody help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure of your project structure but you can add this  in your html/jsp 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">

Comment: You shouldn't have `#` as part of the filename in a URL. That's used to separate the filename from the hash, which is a location on the page to go to after the URL is loaded. It makes no sense to use it in `$.ajax`.

Comment: but that is working in all other browsers.

Comment: I would suggest to remove # from your url and try once more in all browsers. It should work, give it a try.

Comment: +1 to what @Barmar is saying. You should remove the fragment identifier from your URL. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: removed # from url now it is working fine..thanks